# String.replace() strange behaviour

Tags: java, string, replace

I have to replace a string with a blank space. But the replace() methods acts strangely.

Here's the complete string:

```
Prova gestione spoiler.<br/><br/><spoiler>Primo spoiler. :zizi:</spoiler><br/><br/>Un po' di testo qui non fa mai male. :asd:
```

I need to get rid of the first part, the *Prova gestione spoiler* string. I get the first part, the string before the  tag, dynamically, so everytime it's a different string.

Now there's the tricky part. If I do this:

```
temp = text.replace(preSpoilerText, " ");
```

the string won't be replaced. But if I do this:

```
temp = text.replace("Prova gestione spoiler", " ");
```

the string will be replaced.

Is there something I'm missing or is there a better method to replace an entire string?

Thanks.

Comment: How is `preSpoilerText` initialized, caro connazionale? =)

Comment: Have you used a debugger to make sure that `preSpoilerText` is what you think it is?

Comment: @LuigiCortese Caro connazionale, the variable is inizialized as an empty string.

Comment: @Hassan Yes, added tons of Logs and even debugged, the string is the same.

Comment: I suppose you mean that it is initialized as an empty string and then changed dinamically, right?

Comment: We need more details to be able to help you...

Comment: @LuigiCortese Yeah, right.

Comment: For more debugging, try printing out the expression `preSpoilerText.equals("Prova gestione spoiler")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this

```
String foo="Prova gestione spoilerstuff I don't care about";
String bar="Prova gestione spoiler";

System.out.println(foo.replace(bar,""));
System.out.println(foo.replace("Prova gestione spoiler",""));
```

will always return the same result

```
stuff I don't care about
```

Maybe it could be some strange behaviour due to the presence of non alphanumeric chars, like this instructions

```
System.out.println("n".length());
System.out.println("\n".length());
System.out.println("\\n".length());
```

printing

```
1
1
2
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, just found out that there were two "\n"s that were on the original string. Thanks for all your help, mates.

Comment: You should have accepted my answer and commented there, not posting your own =) Considerato anche che il mio intuito ci aveva preso!

Comment: @LuigiCortese Bello come non abbia praticamente visto la tua risposta, programmare fino alle 4 e dormire poco fa male! :P I will accept your aswer as the correct one.

Comment: condividiamo lo stesso destino... ti capisco!